# Handling application end in Nancy web app?

Tags: nancy

I would like to do some logging at the end of the lifetime of my nancy web app.  In an MVC/Webforms ASP.NET application I would use Application_End.  I thought there might be a suitable overridable method in DefaultNancyBootstrapper but can't see one - Is there something equivalent to this in Nancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you would gain from this at all. But we are sort of lacking some information.

When you're working with IIS / System.Web hosting then you can still use the `Application_End` event.

If you're self-hosting in a console then you can just include code that happens after the Console's ReadKey event is raised (or similar)

If you're using OWIN then I'm not sure what you could hook into.

Comment: I'm running it in IIS - I've used this approach previously to troubleshoot issues with user sessions timing out due to app pool shutdown (even though it doesn't always fire).  I'm just starting with Nancy and wondered how to port this across if necessary.  I'd not thought of just trying my existing approach as you suggest - which works fine.  Thanks for the pointers, I need to get a better understanding of system.web vs self-hosting.

Comment: In regards to it not firing, if the application crashes unexpectedly it most often will not fire. Session_End cannot be used for anything other than InProc sessions, which doesn't apply to Nancy anyway since its session handling is entirely different.

Comment: Hi Phill, I'm facing the same issue as rogersillito. What did you mean exactly by "you still can use the Application_End"? Should I create a global asax file manually and also create a class that inherits from httpapplication?
I need to run code when application ends.

Comment: @Auresco82 there's no real 'application end' build into nancy, so if you're hosting on IIS then you can still create a global asax file and use the Application_End in that file. If you're self hosting your out of luck, if you host in a windows service you can hook into the Service Stop method.